# Sorting Custom class in java using Comparable

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I've got this custom class and I want to sort it by saturation and brightness.
I've tried a custom comperator class, but it doesn't work.
Now I've tried to implement `Comparable`. The program runs through the code but doesn't sort the list at the end.

Here is my code.

Part of the testing class:

```
ArrayList<HSBColor> colorList = new ArrayList<HSBColor>(colors.values());

Collections.sort(colorList);

for(HSBColor co : colorList){
    System.out.println(co.toString());
}
```

Custom Class HSBColor

```
     public class HSBColor  implements Comparable<HSBColor>{

    private float H;
    private float S;
    private float B;

    public HSBColor(float h, float s, float b) {
    H = h;
    S = s;
    B = b;
    }

     public float getH() {

    return H;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%.2f %.2f %.2f", H,S,B);
    }

    public void setH(float h) {
    H = h;
    }

     public float getS() {
       return S;
     }

    public void setS(float s) {
    S = s;
    }

    public float getB() {
      return B;
    }

    public void setB(float b) {
       B = b;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(HSBColor o) {
      if(this.getS() > o.getS() && this.getB() >  o.getB()){
          return 1;
       }
      else{
        return -1;
      }
     }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Extra code**

This are the colors before the sort:

```
Color HSB H:28.60465 S:71.07438 B:47.45098
Color HSB H:4.4999995 S:73.059364 B:85.882355 >> This is the one i need
Color HSB H:64.18605 S:79.62963 B:21.176472
Color HSB H:65.714294 S:39.873417 B:61.960785    
Color HSB H:23.333332 S:40.0 B:70.588234
```

This are the colors after the sort

```
28,60 71,07 47,45
65,71 39,87 61,96
23,33 40,00 70,59
4,50 73,06 85,88
64,19 79,63 21,18
```

**EDIT new Algorithm **

This one compares it right, but doesn't sort them right..

```
@Override
public int compareTo(HSBColor o) {

    if(this.getS() > o.getS()) {          
       if(this.getB() >o.getB()){
           return 1;
       }
        else{
           return 0;
       }
    }
    else{
      if(this.getB() < o.getB()){
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want you application to sort on basis of saturation and if saturaion is same than sort on basis of brightness?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* example - without knowing the colours involved, it's very hard to see what's going on. It's bad that your comparator will *never* return 0 though... Also, it's inconsistent for comparisons between two colours where one has a greater brightness and the other has a greater saturation... what do you want the result to be in that case?

Comment: give some sample values , for saturation and brightness and let us know what output you need

Comment: Output added sorry for the non /n..

Answer (score 1):

Your `compareTo` method doesn't define a proper ordering.

Suppose that this.getS() > o.getS() but this.getB() <  o.getB().

this.compareTo(o) would return -1, but o.compareTo(this) would also return -1.

If A < B and B < A this is not a proper ordering.

A proper ordering would first compare by the more important property, and then, in case of equality, by the less important property.

For example :

```
@Override
public int compareTo(HSBColor o) {
  if(this.getS() > o.getS()){
      return 1;
  } else if (this.getS() < o.getS()) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    if (this.getB() >  o.getB()) {
      return 1;
    } else if (this.getB() <  o.getB()) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds right but doesn't do it :(

Output:
Color HSB H:28.60465 S:71.07438 B:47.45098
Color HSB H:4.4999995 S:73.059364 B:85.882355
Color HSB H:64.18605 S:79.62963 B:21.176472
Color HSB H:65.714294 S:39.873417 B:61.960785
Color HSB H:23.333332 S:40.0 B:70.588234
65,71 39,87 61,96
23,33 40,00 70,59
28,60 71,07 47,45
4,50 73,06 85,88
64,19 79,63 21,18

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue around compareTo method. You should use it like:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(HSBColor o) {//if saturation is equal then compare brightness.
    if (this.S == o.getS()) {
        return Float.compare(B, o.getB());
    }

    return Float.compare(S, o.getS());
}
```